# How to update UI on chain request with Rx Java

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I would like to update UI 2 times on chain request.

First update UI after request `getUserByID()` completed. Second on `getParentName()` completed but when I try to update UI on first request and get error cause of thread problem.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Sample code

```
API.getUserByID("USER ID")
        .flatMap(user-> {
            // How to update UI here?
            return API.getParentName(user.getId()))
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(parent-> {
            // It's ok to update UI cause of on main thread.
            parentTextView.setText(parent.getName())
        });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want update UI on observable emission, so you need specify observer thread for that observable.
Then you should use `doOnNext` operator, that invokes on observer thread:

```
API.getUserByID("USER ID")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext(user_ -> {calls on observer thread})
        .flatMap(user-> {
            return API.getParentName(user.getId()))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        })
        .subscribe(parent-> {
            // It's ok to update UI cause of on main thread.
            parentTextView.setText(parent.getName())
        });
```

Comment: I can update TextView on `doOnNext()` but it throw error "StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy" on `subscribe()`

Comment: Did you mean `NetworkOnMainThreadException`? Try apply .`subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()` to every network observable, not `flatmap`, I upd answer

Comment: Thx, you are save my life :)